# Screen capture at more than 1000 FPS

Tags: video, video-recording, screen-casting

i would like to know if there is a hardware device, a software that would produce PC screen capture at more than 1000 FPS ?

The highest i could get under Linux with a custom program is around 400 FPS.

I suppose there is several hardware/software limitations, if there is no hardware or software, any hints on how can this be achieved ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your screen even outputting that high of a frame rate?  The data rates you are talking about at 1000fps are staggering.  At 8 bit color and 1080p video, that's over 6GB per second of data to deal with for 1000fps.

Comment: I don't think it have to do with the screen output except on the hardware side depending on how the screen is grabbed, my question is quite generic thus i just wonder if > 1000 FPS is possible either in pure software or hardware (from GPU or from display)

Comment: What is the purpose behind your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't rule out specialized hardware devices that might be able to, but 1080p video at 1000fps produces 6GBps of raw data at 8 bit color.  That's 48 gbps, which exceeds the highest standards of most current connectors.  Display port 1.4 is just shy of 26gbps and barely covers half of the needed data rate for a 1000fps 1080p data stream.

You might be able to pull it off with a quad-link 12G-SDI setup, but I'm not aware of any hardware that can work with quad link 12G-SDI.

As far as handling it internally, no modern single SSD can handle the raw data rate.  An ultra top-end PCI express SSD can still only write around 2GBps, so you'd need over 3 of them working in parallel to keep up with the raw data rate.  At PCI express 3 speeds, you'd need 7 lanes minimum for the data transfer alone, so you could theoretically handle it with a PCI-E 3.0 x8 card, but you also need to take in to account the data that needs to be sent to the card for rendering at that rate as well.

You might be able to reduce this a bit by processing in CUDA on the card itself, but that's still an extremely high amount of processing to be doing while also trying to render whatever it is you are rendering at 1000fps, which, btw, you can't even display at 1000fps because there's no way to get a 1000fps feed out of the computer or display it.

Overall, I suspect the reason you don't find any software to do this is that it simply isn't possible or practical to do at this time.  Limits are probably set based on what seems like rational limitations for the capabilities of current hardware.

Comment: Thank for your answer, this made me think that I did not precise the images resolution, I am perfectly fine with 720p or even something like 640x480 or even less in width

Comment: @grz - what are you actually trying to accomplish?  That might help us provide better input.  Altering things like color depth might also be a possibility to simplify things greatly.

Comment: The color depth could be altered but i absolutely need two color components (red/green for example), this is for audio experiments, the human ear events resolution is on the microseconds scale

Comment: @grz - ok, why does it need to be a screen capture then?  Why can't it be a visualization that is produced to correspond with timing data?  If you are trying to form a visualization of some type, it seems like there are likely better ways to accomplish it.

Comment: Because it will be audio events in the end and not visualizations, there is no need of displaying it, the data will be used for audio concerns

Comment: @grz right, but I'm trying to understand what you are trying to capture.  A screen capture might not be the best option for what you are trying to do.